# Best Backbone plugin for cascading select boxes

Tags: backbone.js

I need to make a form with cascading select boxes.  Meaning, the options of a select box depend on the option selected of the previous select box.  Does anyone have any opinions on which is the best Backbone plugin for the job? Or should I just use the event aggregator pattern?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this post, its a way of doing this, but yes you could also do it with events in the views.

http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/07/25/cascading-select-boxes-with-backbone-js/